# Serve multiple spark uis from the same pod, host and port

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, openshift, spark-ui

I have a problem with `Apache Spark` (version 3.3.1) on `k8s`.

#### In short

I want to make multiple spark web uis accessible from outside the `K8S` cluster, when they run on the same `pod`. In addition to it, when I would run this:

```py
print(sc.uiWebUrl)
```

It would be "clickable" and I could access it from outside the cluster.

#### Long story

I work on a workspace for people who work with `Apache Spark`. The workspace would be a **`pod`** in `K8S` I want to let them run multiple `Apache Spark` programs, and I want those programs' `UI` would be displayed and accessible for the clients (for `UX` reasons).

To make it displayed, I need the value of the `Apache Spark` context's `UI` web `URL` value.

The `UI`'s web `URL` would look like this:

```
http://{driver's host or public DNS if defined}:{driver's UI port}
```

I have tried to define the public `DNS` to an ingress's host value I have defined. But I can serve ports 80 (`HTTP`) and/or 443 (`HTTPS`) **only**.

So, when I run **multiple** `Apache Spark` programs, It would not work, as I can't serve multiple ports under the same host.

##### Other points

- I don't have `nginx` ingress in my `K8S` cluster. I have `OpenShift` cluster.
- I would prefer to use `K8S` objects as much as possible.
- I would prefer that the clients would configure `Apache Spark` as least as possible.
- I would prefer that the UI web URL of the `Apache Spark`'s context would be set when creating the context, meaning before the `pyspark-shell` displays the welcome screen.

#### Thanks

Thanks ahead for reading my problem, and thanks ahead for helping me. Any help would be appreciated.